Springboot method timer
I have a usecase to track execution time of a method in springboot. If execution time exceeds the specific time then I need to throw an exception. I am looking for options to handle that in java and springboot. The method has interaction with redis cache something like mentioned below. Also the important aspect of this usecase is that exception should be thrown without any error in the calling method but purely based on execution time without capturing end time.
public CacheResponse getValue(String key) {
        try{
            return  redisJedisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);
        } catch(Exception e){
            LOGGER.error("{}: Error fetching data with key {} {}", className,key,e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }


I think a completableFuture should resolve your problem. By wrapping your task in a completableFuture and setting a timeout i.e. .withTimeout(long amount, TimeUnit unit) it will throw a timeoutexception when the specified time is reached.

I think you wont even need the withTimeout method if you create the CompletableFuture and call .get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) on it

I would use the Resillience4J TimeLimiter. This also has integration for Spring Boot which will give you easy configuration and also nice metrics which you can use for a dashboard or to create reports or triggers.

You should use CompletableFuture with Executor service, in this case:
Here is an example code below :
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class TimeoutWrapper {

private static final long MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 1000; // in milliseconds
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public <T> T executeWithTimeout(Callable<T> task) throws ExecutionTimeExceededException {
    Future<T> future = executor.submit(task);
    try {
        return future.get(MAX_EXECUTION_TIME, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        future.cancel(true);
        throw new ExecutionTimeExceededException("Method execution exceeded the maximum allowed time of " + MAX_EXECUTION_TIME + " ms");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}

With
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CacheService {

@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, CacheResponse> redisJedisTemplate;

private final TimeoutWrapper timeoutWrapper = new TimeoutWrapper();

public CacheResponse getValue(String key) {
    try {
        return timeoutWrapper.executeWithTimeout(() -> redisJedisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key));
    } catch (ExecutionTimeExceededException e) {
        LOGGER.error("{}: Execution time exceeded for key {} {}", className, key, e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("{}: Error fetching data with key {} {}", className, key, e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}


Here you are letting the method to execute and then capturing the end time. My use case is if the redis cache hangs and doensn't throw error then the above code will not have endtime. So instead of relying on endtime, I need to have a counter in millisecs and as soon as the counter reaches to max delay throw an error. Not sure this code will handle that

@MonishDas  Then you shoud use CompletableFuture with ExecutorService, i updated my solution. I updated my solution.

CompletableFuture also has utility methods that make it simpler to run a task by providing suppliers/functions/consumers without any ExecutorService setup since it will be run by ForkJoinPool. you could probably just use CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> redisJedisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key)).get(amount, units); with all the other try catch of course

Thanks for sharing. I had the similar solution using completable future in mind. My only concern is that in a high tps scenario currently 10000tps how much container resources will be stressed with this approach

@pebbleunit ForkJoinPool also used Threadpool, also Executor service, but i agree that using CompletableFuture.supplyAsync would be simpler. Thanks for the info.

@pebbleunit and Beck. Can this approach work even for setting into redis cache for something like redisJedisTemplate.opsForValue().set(redisCacheKey, response, Duration.ofSeconds(cacheTTLInSeconds));

@MonishDas I am not sure it will work because this method set is generic

This works with CompletableFuture.runAsync. thanks @драган-јованковић
